# Put JSON items into a WPF GRID in C#

Tags: c#, json, wpf

How to put the items in a JSON string in a WPF grid?

```
{  
    "success":"true",
    "response":{  
        "Page":1,
        "PageFirst":1,
        "PageLast":1,
        "PageRecordFirst":1,
        "PageRecordLast":2147483647,
        "PageSize":2147483647,
        "RecordCount":2,
        "ResultSet":[  
            {  
                "CompanyId":1,
                "CompanyName":"Focus",
                "ComputedProjectProgressAll":39.000000,
                "ComputedProjectProgressCurrent":39.000000,
                "ComputedProjectProgressExpected":86.00,
                "ComputedTaskCountAll":434,
                "ComputedTaskCountCurrent":354,
                "CreateDate":"\/Date(1421947846600-0800)\/",
                "CreateUserId":1,
                "CreateUserName":"MobiCloud Admin",
                "CustomerId":1,
                "CustomerName":"MobiCloud",
                "Description":"Obra 001",
                "Id":7,
                "IsActive":true,
                "ModifyDate":"\/Date(1421947846600-0800)\/",
                "ModifyUserId":1,
                "ModifyUserName":"MobiCloud Admin",
                "Name":"Obra Desenv 001",
                "Status":0
            },
            {  
                "CompanyId":1,
                "CompanyName":"Focus",
                "ComputedProjectProgressAll":69.000000,
                "ComputedProjectProgressCurrent":69.000000,
                "ComputedProjectProgressExpected":100.00,
                "ComputedTaskCountAll":199,
                "ComputedTaskCountCurrent":199,
                "CreateDate":"\/Date(1422298868660-0800)\/",
                "CreateUserId":1,
                "CreateUserName":"MobiCloud Admin",
                "CustomerId":1,
                "CustomerName":"MobiCloud",
                "Description":"sadasdsad",
                "Id":8,
                "IsActive":true,
                "ModifyDate":"\/Date(1422298868660-0800)\/",
                "ModifyUserId":1,
                "ModifyUserName":"MobiCloud Admin",
                "Name":"Obra Desenv 002",
                "Status":0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: erm.. English please. Formatting please.

Comment: Even in English this is an awful question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create a c# class equivalent to JSON. use http://json2csharp.com/ to create c# class. Then you need to deserialize your JSON string use JSON.NET from http://json.codeplex.com/. Now you have got all the things setup. Now you can assing these data into WPF controls. I have assigned the response resultset into one datagrid. Refer the below code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        string str = File.ReadAllText("1.txt");
        RootObject deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str);
        dgr.ItemsSource = deserializedObject.response.ResultSet;
    }
}

public class ResultSet
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public double ComputedProjectProgressAll { get; set; }
    public double ComputedProjectProgressCurrent { get; set; }
    public double ComputedProjectProgressExpected { get; set; }
    public int ComputedTaskCountAll { get; set; }
    public int ComputedTaskCountCurrent { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int CreateUserId { get; set; }
    public string CreateUserName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifyUserId { get; set; }
    public string ModifyUserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageFirst { get; set; }
    public int PageLast { get; set; }
    public int PageRecordFirst { get; set; }
    public long PageRecordLast { get; set; }
    public long PageSize { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    public List<ResultSet> ResultSet { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string success { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
 <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgr"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: var objeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WEBTOP_FVS.Util.ItensCronograma>(strJSON);